# What agencies are affected by government shutdown?

Tags: united-states, government-shutdown

I did a search and visited a few government websites, but I still can't seem to find all the agencies affected by the shutdown.

Comment: I can't see any reason to justify the downvotes. But even more baffling are the close votes. The question is as to the point as it can possibly be. I also did a search for this and could not find any official list of agencies affected by the shutdown, so the answer is not obvious.

Comment: The question in the title is answered at [Why is 3/4 of the US federal government unaffected by a shutdown?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37886/why-is-3-4-of-the-us-federal-government-unaffected-by-a-shutdown). The part regarding racial breakdown seems to be rather broad to be answered definitely.

Comment: @Panda I don't think the title question is answered in your link. The OP specifically asks for agencies, which I would assume includes non-governmental entities such as non-profits (but admittedly I'm not knowledgeable of the nomenclature). Further I would assume this change in scale to be relevant given this question final objective (as stated by the OP). Which incidentally I don't see as "too broad". Given the number of people that could be affected, which of those are actually being affected, grouped by ethnicity. Difficult to say maybe, but not too broad.

Comment: @armatita The question does say “government websites” so I’d assume non-profits which are not part of the federal government are not included. IMO it’s broad in the sense that it’s difficult to ascertain who’s affected, given that there are many 9 affected government departments and many agencies under these departments have their own guidelines regarding “essential employees”. It’s difficult to determine what’s the exact number of employees who are furloughed and how many are called back to work unpaid. Even if the exact number is known, we might not know the ethnicity breakdown.

Comment: @Panda The question refers "government websites" as a source. We can't really conclude if non-profits (or other non-governmental organizations) are included in the question or not. I would find it strange if not, given the stated purpose. And yes I agree this is difficult but the question is valid (particularly given Trump past comments on the majority of the affected being democrats). I would not be surprised to find a research paper, by some academics, somewhere, on this subject.

Comment: Even if the question doesn't include NGOs, the linked answer is incomplete for the purpose of this question.  There exist independent agencies like the Office of Personnel Management, and it also does not list the status of the Executive Office of the President, which is also not a department level entity.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Not to mention that closing "questions" as duplicates is about closing "questions" as duplicates, not answers. This question deserves to be asked in it's own right. Closing this question as a duplicate of another just because that different question happens to contain an answer with the information requested doesn't do much for people searching this question in Google.